# Data from mongoDB to java

Tags: java, string, mongodb, stream

i wanna create hyperlink to website which link is data from mongoDB

but the result of data is `[ "http://thehackernews.com/2013/12/judge-ruled-nsa-telephone-metadata.html"]`

how to remove [(white space)"........"]

even on java or on mongoDB

the data from mongoDB is `http://thehackernews.com/2013/12/judge-ruled-nsa-telephone-metadata.html` but when i print it on java the result is always `[ "http://thehackernews.com/2013/12/judge-ruled-nsa-telephone-metadata.html"]`

i've tried to cut the string with

```
String li=object.get("link").toString();
```

- `String[] splitStr = li.split("\\s+");`
- `String cut=li.split("\\s");`
- `String hasil=li.substring(li.indexOf("[")+1,li.indexOf("]"));`

nothing succes, then i think i can set the output from mongoDB (but i dont understand), so far i just tried to cut the string from java

any solution guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try the following:

```
String str2=li.substring(li.indexOf("\"")+1,li.lastIndexOf(("\"")));
```

Comment: btw how to write down "/"" maually?
because on my netbeans if i write " then manually written "" ...

Comment: You need to delete the closing `"` that NetBeans automatically generates for you. Simple delete the extra `"`. That's all. You might copy from here too.

Comment: once more sir, how about if 
from : 
[ "Wednesday, March 30, 2016" , "\n" , "\n"] 
to become : 
Wednesday, March 30, 2016

*for the netbeans problem, it can be fixed if i write \ first before " :) thanks..

Comment: Could you please try `String str3=li.substring(li.indexOf("\"")+1,li.indexOf(("\" ,")));` for your second problem?

Comment: hi mates i wanna ask
how to remove every " , "\n" , "\n in the middle of paragraph? if the sitioation like this [ "\n" , "\nThe " , " (Federal Bureau of Investigation) over a locked iPhone that belonged to one of the San Bernardino shooters may be over, but the Department of Justice (DoJ) are back in front of a judge with a similar request." , "\n" , "\nThe American Civil Liberties Union (ACLU) has discovered publicly available " , " that revealed the government has asked Google?s assistance to help the Feds hack into at least nine locked Android smartphones citing the " , "."

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me

```
 li = li.substring(str.indexOf("\"")+1);
    li = li.substring(0, str.indexOf("\""));
```

Comment: thanks before mate :)
btw do you know how to change 
from : [ "Wednesday, March 30, 2016" , "\n" , "\n"] to become : Wednesday, March 30, 2016

Comment: Use the same script.

Comment: using the same script its give result

Monday, November 30, 2015" , "\n" , "\n 

the result before script is

[ "Wednesday, March 30, 2016" , "\n" , "\n"] 

sorry sir if i tell so many question, it so confusing...

Comment: class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str ="[\"Wednesday, March 30, 2016\" , \"\n\" , \"\n\"]";
        str = str.substring(str.indexOf("\"")+1);
        str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("\""));

        System.out.println(str);
    }
} , This the script that I use to test the result and it gives me that Wednesday, March 30, 2016

Comment: thanks mate, this way is right too...now i have 2 ways to cutting the strings on java :) thanks for helping e so much..

Comment: yepyep...
btw do you have some experience using mongoDB?
i wanna ask about searching on multiple collections and multiple elements..

Comment: Yeah, can you explain more (some examples if it's possible) ?

Comment: i wanna create search coloumn on my site, then i have database 'face' which is have 2 collections fb(have object which every elements have link,body,date) and titles(have object which every elements have link,body,date)...how can i search it?

i only success with 1 collections by 1 elements object(like link only or body only)

here is my script on mongoDB 'db.fb.find( { link: /bc/ },{body:/bc/},{date:/bc/} )'

how can i write it on java api with using 'fb' and 'titles' collections and all of elements concurrently on one searching coloumn?